# Unable to receive DatagramPackets

Tags: java, udp, packet, datagram

I am not able to receive `DatagramPacket`s. With wireshark however I could verify that packets are arriving. I have seen similar questions with possible solutions on this site, but they didn't help me much (I have already tried deactivating the firewall, etc.). My code is simple:

```
// Create socket
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5554);
socket.connect(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1"), 5554);

try {           
    while(!stop) {
        keepAwake(); // This sends some bytes using socket.send(...), works perfectly fine
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[2048], 2048);
        socket.receive(packet); // Does not work :(
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] Packet received!"); // Never happens

        // Parse packet
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Also no exceptions are thrown
}
```

What could be the problem here? By the way, my OS is Ubuntu 12.10 and the packets are sent from a server written in C whose source code I don't have (does DatagramSocket only recieve DatagramPackets sent from a Java DatagramSocket?).

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: The IP address `192.168.1.1` is usually reserved for the router or switch you are using.  Are you sure this is the address of your PC?

Comment: Actually, I'm connecting to an AR.Drone which acts as a router. I'm sure this is the correct address as sending of packets works (and the drone responds).

Comment: UDP doesn't have connections. It can subscribe to packets which are sent to your address or broadcast or multicast. I am concerned that this address doesn't appear to be any of these and you appear to be trying to snoop on packets sent to another address which you might not be able to do without being root. (i.e. without promiscuous mode)

Comment: Wireshark tells me packets are sent to 192.168.1.2. I have multiple network adapters so is it possible to specify the local address the Socket should listen to? Or is what I just said complete nonsense (I'm new to networking and udp...)?

Comment: If they are being sent to `192.168.1.2` then that is what you should listen to.

Comment: So should I `socket.connect` to 192.168.1.2 to receive and use a separate socket to send packets to 192.168.1.1?

Comment: Repeat after me "UDP doesn't have connections".  The address you specify is the *destination* you are *listening* too.  You are not connecting to a machine/server or anything. e.g. if you use multicast/broadcast, there won't even be a machine with that address.

Comment: "UDP doesn't have connections." So if packets are sent to 192.168.1.2 I construct a socket like this: `socket = new DatagramSocket(5554, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"));`? And to send packets to 192.168.1.1 I use: `socket.send(new DatagramPacket(new byte[]{content}, length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1"), 5554));`?

Comment: AFAIK, That should work, provided you are running as root.  Otherwise you won't be able to see packets which were not sent to your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Try bind() with an IP of 0.0.0.0 and the port you want instead of "connect()".

**Edit:** Actually, the construtor already binds it, ommiting the connect should be sufficient.

From the doc:

> When a socket is connected to a remote address, packets may only be sent to or received from that address.

This is probably why you aren't receiving the packets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but it throws a `SocketException` saying it's already bound.

Comment: Please provide the exact message of the exception. It is possible that the port is already occupied by another application.

However, I just noticed you already bind the socket in the constructor, so try to simply leave out the connect() line (and possibly bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of leaving it to Java (it might bind to localhost by default).

Also, check with netstat -ul if the port is already occupied if your Java application is not running. You can also use netstat to check where your app listens.

Comment: I have already tried to leave out the connect line. Running `netstat -ul` doesn't show the port, so I don't think it's occupied. All this surprises me as connecting as I did it at the beginning worked and even allowed me to send data.

Comment: Please try binding explicitly to 0.0.0.0 as described in the edit, and paste the output of `netstat -ul` *while your app is running*

Comment: Constructing the DatagramSocket with just a port number implicitly binds it to 0.0.0.0. Not localhost. This is not a fruitful line of enquiry.

Comment: OK, I tried to bind using the following: `socket = new DatagramSocket(); socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 5554));` Is this correct (it still isn't working)? The netstat ouput is here: http://pastebin.com/rD0fmmhD

Comment: Interesting - netstat doesn't show any listener on 5554, so it appears the socket wasn't bound when netstat ran. Are you sure your application was running and had created the socket? @EJP: you're right, I should read the entire documentation...

Comment: `socket = new DatagramSocket(5554);` throws a `BindException: Address already in use`...

Comment: Then something has already bound (and should show on netstat). Is the above example code in a single simple main() function of a console app for testing? If not, try it.

Answer (score 0):

If 192.168.1.1 is a router, the packets presumably aren't originating from there, so you shouldn't be connecting to it. You don't have any need to call connect() at all actually, unless you need to filter out packets from other sources. Or else connect to the actual source address of the packets.

And no, a DatagramSocket isn't restricted to receiving from other DatagramSockets.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, I'm trying to receive packets from an AR.Drone which acts as a router. Using wireshark shows that the packets are originating at 192.168.1.1, and sending commands (also via DatagramSocket, but on port 5556) works as the AR.Drone responds.

Comment: @laobeylu And as I just said above, unless the router is also the ultimate source of the packets, you shouldn't be connecting to it: you should either not connect to anything or connect to the ultimate source, which isn't your router but a C server according to your OP. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: OK, I'll try not to connect to anything.

Comment: As I understand it, the C server is running on the "router", so wouldn't it be the ultimate source in that case?

Comment: @laobeylu Now that you've clarified that, yes, but you don't sound too certain about it, and a server running in a router sounds pretty odd. What happened when you removed the connect?

Comment: Well, removing the connect had no effect... Also, it's not really a router, it's this thing here: http://ardrone2.parrot.com/ I think the problem is I'm not correctly telling it to send it's data to my PC. I'll try to find out more...

Comment: @laobeylu One of the problems is that you are being incredibly vague about what this system is made of. The router is the source and it also isn't a router?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
The problem was not the `DatagramSocket`: The packets I needed to receive were sent to some weird address (not my PC). As the thing whose packets I wanted to receive is an AR.Drone I finally managed to tell it that it should send packets to my PC. Now I can receive them!

Comment: But you said above 'with Wireshark I could verify that packets are arriving' and 'Wireshark tells me packets are sent to 192.168.1.2'. You are now contradicting yourself, not for the first time in this futile thread.